# How to set async/await inside a for loop for bulkwrite?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise

For some reason, I cannot find related article on how to set await inside a for loop. My idea is that I want to chunk bulkWrite in every 500 entries.

The await outside the for loop works fine, however, inside the for loop, I can't figure out how to implement it.

Thanks a lot.

```
let bulkUpdateOps = [];
let counter = 0;
let bulkWriteChunkResult = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    bulkUpdateOps.push({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(itemId) },
        update: {
          $set: { stocks: i },
        },
      },
    });

    counter += 1;

    // make bulk update in chunk of 500 items per update
    if (counter % 500 === 0) {
        Item.collection.bulkWrite(
          bulkUpdateOps,
          { ordered: true, w: 1 },
          (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            bulkWriteChunkResult.push(result);
          },
        );
      });

      console.log(bulkWriteResult);
      bulkUpdateOps = []; // re-initialize for new bulk update
    }    
}

// if update counter is not over 500 entries
if (counter % 500) {
  const bulkWriteResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Item.collection.bulkWrite(
      bulkUpdateOps,
      { ordered: true, w: 1 },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(result);
      }
    );
  });

  console.log(bulkWriteResult); // returns expected bulk write result
} else {
  const chunkResult = await Promise.all(bulkWriteChunkResult);
  console.log(chunkResult); // UNFORTUNATELY, this returns an empty array
}

// TODO: do something with the bulkWrite result after await
```

Comment: As long as the for- loop is inside an async function, literally just do it like normal. If you await it inside a for- loop, it will wait before it goes to the next part of the loop. The same, however, does not apply to a functional loop like Array.forEach, but what you've done here is straight forward.

Comment: @TKoL Eslint is emitting "Unexpected await inside loop"

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Oh, so it's not an error, it's an ESLINT error

Comment: What is the problem that you are experiencing? For me there seems to be information missing, but I guess it is because you have dummed down the code (ie where is `itemId`, why use a counter and not the length or the array), is 1000 a fixed number or is this also just for the question created like that?

Comment: How about just filling an array with your promises and await that one after the for loop?

Comment: @Icepickle no don't mind the variables/values, I just use them as sample, like 1000... it is not my actual code :)

Comment: @Icepickle It works in for loop also. `function delayedPromise(value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 1000)
    })
}
var test = async () => {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        console.log(await delayedPromise(index + 1))
    }
}
test()`

Comment: @RahulSharma I didn't say it didn't work in a for loop :) But from the code shared, I don't even see the need to await the result, as it seems to me that there is no correlation between the writes and reads, so why not simply do the writing, save the promise and await all after the loop

Comment: @Woppi here's an example of it working in a for-loop and not a forEach as I explained https://jsfiddle.net/gqyLjq6f/8/

Comment: @Woppi is your loop inside an async function? you haven't shown the context that this code exists in, and if it isn't wrapped inside an async function then it won't work.

Comment: @TKoL yes it is inside an async function... basically the await bulkWrite (when entries are below 500) is working... it is the above 500 entries inside the for loop I am trying to figure out.... might need a little more experimentation

Comment: But do you really need to await the result?

Comment: @Icepickle yes because I need to return it to front-end. I will try the push you are talking about.

Comment: That would also work with an `await Promise.all`, my question was mainly if you needed to await the results of the bulkupdate for the next reading, if you don't then you really don't need the await in the for loop (and you could simply slice and reduce/map instead)

Comment: @Icepickle I have updated my above code and followed your advice unfortunately, it returns an empty array. Hmmm.

Comment: @Woppi In how far can I use lets say demo code to demonstrate 2 solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally believe you are over complicating your current solution, but without seeing actual code, that is hard to say if this is the case.

For one, as far as I can see, your code doesn't really have to wait in the for loop, it seems your bulk writes are fine if they are fired away, and just waited for as the result of your update.

Another complication (as far as I can see from the code), is the double check to see if you sent all items to your server. If your source data comes as an array, or something that can be transformed in place, there is no need for neither the for loop as the double check.

The code supplied does make the assumption that your updates do not influence the coming updates (in both versions, nl, the `performBulkUpdate` and `performSyncBulkUpdate`)

This code is used to split your source array, and create the bulk items, then executes the action, and saves the promise, afterwards the `promise.all( results )` is awaited.

```
// as long as i is smaller than the length of the array
while (i < content.length) {
  // take the amount of items, perform transformation and save the promise
  let itemsToWrite = content.slice(i, i + bulkSize ).map( transformation );
  results.push( action( itemsToWrite ) );
  // increase the index with the bulkSize
  i += itemsToWrite.length;
}
```

Of course, if for some reason, you have to wait till each write operation has finished, then you have to change the approach a bit, by awaiting each single write operation, either like this:

```
// as long as i is smaller than the length of the array
while (i < content.length) {
  let itemsToWrite = content.slice(i, i + bulkSize ).map( transformation );
  results.push( await action( itemsToWrite ) );
  // increase the index with the bulkSize
  i += itemsToWrite.length;
}
```

below is a snippet demonstrating both approaches

```js
// source array that must be bulkupdated
const source = [10, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15, 33, 47, 42, 63, 77, 99];

// some random action that returns a promise
const bulkWrite = (arr) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    setTimeout( () => 
      resolve( arr.map( i => { return { id: i && i.sourceId }; } ) )
    , 100 );
  } );
};

// concat arrays together
const flatten = (arr) => arr.reduce( (current, item) => current.concat( item ), [] );

// dummy transformation suiting the write operation
const transformItem = (item) => ({ sourceId: item });

// the bulk update (default bulkSize = 3)
const performBulkChange = async ( content, action, transformation, bulkSize = 3 ) => {
  // the array containing the promises
  const results = [];
  let i = 0;
  
  // as long as i is smaller than the length of the array
  while (i < content.length) {
    // take the amount of items, perform transformation and save the promise
    let itemsToWrite = content.slice(i, i + bulkSize ).map( transformation );
    results.push( action( itemsToWrite ) );
    // increase the index with the bulkSize
    i += itemsToWrite.length;
  }
  return await Promise.all( results );
};

const performSyncBulkChange = async ( content, action, transformation, bulkSize = 3 ) => {
  // all results
  const results = [];
  let i = 0;
  
  // as long as i is smaller than the length of the array
  while (i < content.length) {
    let itemsToWrite = content.slice(i, i + bulkSize ).map( transformation );
    results.push( await action( itemsToWrite ) );
    // increase the index with the bulkSize
    i += itemsToWrite.length;
  }
  return results;
};

console.log( 'starting' );

// slower, takes at least 100 ms per bulk
performSyncBulkChange( source, bulkWrite, transformItem, 5 )
  .then( flatten )
  .then( result => console.log( result ) );

// bulk change will be faster, it doesn't wait
performBulkChange( source, bulkWrite, transformItem )
  .then( flatten )
  .then( result => console.log( result ) );
```